# How can I easily get the path of a file inside a folder in my solution in Visual Studio with C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

I have created a folder inside a project in my solution using the `"right click -> Add -> New folder -> folder1"` method, and now my solution explorer looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way for me to programmatically access files inside this folder (ex: sampleFile.xml) **from code**, other than get the path of the executable and go from there?

**Edit:** I want to know if there's a more elegant solution provided by VS/C#, I know I can construct the path using the executable path or base directory.

For example, found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406474/referencing-text-file-visual-studio-c-sharp) : if I add the file as a resource (Right click on project -> Properties -> Resources -> Add Resource) a "Resource" folder is generated in my solution explorer :

[image]

and I can get the content of the file easily like this :

```
var newFile = Properties.Resources.newFile1;
```

Is there something similar for other non-resource files in the solution and can I get the path of the files in a similar way?

Comment: In what context do you want that code of yours to run? A separate program running on your development machine? A Visual Studio extension running while you have your solution open? etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Test` is your main project, then the file can be accessed via:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Folder1\SampleFile.xml"
```

(This assumes that:  (a) you want to access it from within Visual Studio, or (b) that whatever install mechanism you use places `Folder1` within the start directory of the application.)

Comment: If the proper build or copy action has been set.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I am making that assumption, so answer updated accordingly.